# Confusion about many-to-one, many-to-many LSTM architectures in Keras

Tags: neural-network, sequence, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My task is the following: I have a (black box) method which computes a sequence starting from an initial element. At each step, my method reads an input from an external source of memory and outputs an action which potentially changes this memory. You can think of this method as a function `f: (external state, reading) -> action`. I want to train an ANN to learn `f()`, which means I want to be able to take my trained model, feed it an input, get the predicted action, use it to change the external state and repeat this process indefinitely, one step at a time.

Because of the nature of `f()` I know that the ANN must be recurrent and stateful, but I'm not so sure about the rest. It makes sense to train it to map sequences of readings into sequences of actions, but it only makes sense if the model is able to fuse each reading with the action outputted in the last step, and I'm not sure how to enforce that.

But most importantly: After training my model with a given sequence length (readings^N -> actions^N), how can I make it output predictions one step at a time (sequence length = 1)? Is this possible?